# need to read from line a to line b in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls
Color 0A

:Read
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=WinSCP-5.11.2-ReadMe.txt
call :ReadInLines
call :EchoLines

echo insert other code here
pause
endlocal
(goto) 2>nul

:ReadInLines
set Counter=0
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in ('type %file%') do (
    set /a Counter+=1
    title Lines In File: !Counter!
    set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
)
(goto) 2>nul

:EchoLines
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do (echo %%C. !Line_%%C!)
pause
```

So this is my code at the moment

It is able to successfully read and output the file as whole but I want to work on a way that doesn't require scrolling (for bigger files)

basically what i need to be able to do is read a certain amount of lines

example:

read lines 1 to 8 but also read lines 5 to 13

basically i need to be able to interchange the numbers it reads to, a label to call is preferred

finished code:

call.bat:

```
@echo off
cls
Color 0A

:: double call
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 1 8
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 9 20
pause

:: multiselect (a) (b) (a) (b) etc...
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 1 20 23 29
pause

:: call then calling outside text range (outputs first but not second)
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 1 8
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 80 100
pause

:: another call outside text range (outputs nothing)
call text-read-lines-alt.bat 90 100
pause
```

text-read-lines-alt.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=WinSCP-5.11.2-ReadMe.txt

SET "parms=%*"

call :ReadInLines
call :EchoLines

echo insert other code here
endlocal
(goto) 2>nul

:ReadInLines
set Counter=0
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in ('type %file%') do (
    set /a Counter+=1
    title Lines In File: !Counter!

    CALL :gate !counter!

    IF DEFINED RECORD set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
)
(goto) 2>nul

:EchoLines
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do IF DEFINED line_%%C (echo %%C. !Line_%%C!)
GOTO :EOF

:gate
SET "record="
IF NOT DEFINED parms GOTO :EOF 
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*" %%x IN ("%parms%") DO (
    IF %1 gtr %%y SET "parms=%%z"&GOTO gate
    IF %1 geq %%x SET "record=Y"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

and here is what all the hard work went to: http://old-school-gamer.tk/batch/text-reader/releases/
:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=WinSCP-5.11.2-ReadMe.txt
set file=100lines.txt

SET "parms=%*"

call :ReadInLines
call :EchoLines

echo insert other code here
pause
endlocal
(goto) 2>nul

:ReadInLines
set Counter=0
for /f "DELIMS=" %%i in ('type %file%') do (
    set /a Counter+=1
    title Lines In File: !Counter!

    CALL :gate !counter!

    IF DEFINED RECORD set "Line_!Counter!=%%i"
)
(goto) 2>nul

:EchoLines
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do IF DEFINED line_%%C (echo %%C. !Line_%%C!)
SET /a count=0
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do IF DEFINED line_%%C (
 SET /a count +=1
 echo !count!. !Line_%%C!
)
GOTO :EOF

:gate
SET "record="
IF NOT DEFINED parms GOTO :EOF 
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*" %%x IN ("%parms%") DO (
 IF %1 gtr %%y SET "parms=%%z"&GOTO gate
 IF %1 geq %%x SET "record=Y"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I started by recording `parms`=the command-tail. My `100lines.txt` file is simply a file containing 100 lines "line 1".."line100"

`CALL`ing the `:gate` procedure sets or clears `record` to specify whether the line in `counter` should be recorded or not. `if defined` works on the current status of the target variable - defined or not.

The `:gate` routine examines the `parms` string, assigning `%%x` to the first token, `%%y` to the second and `%%z` to the remainder of the parameters provided. If the current line number in `%1` (from the calling loop) is greater then the second parameter, then assign `parms` to *the rest of the string* (which removes thefirst two parameters) and try again. `parms` will eventually become empty, so simply don't try processing it.

If the second parameter is not greater than the current line, see whether the current line is greater than or equal to the first parameter. If so, set `record` to a value so it becomes *defined* and hence the calling loop will record it.

So - say `params` is `10 13 21 28`. `%%x` will be set to `10`, `%%y` to `13` and `%%z` to `21 28`. Until line 9, the line number will not be `geq` 10, so `record` remains clear. For lines 10 to 13, `record` will be set and the line recorded, on line 14, 14 is greater than 13, so `parms` becomes `21 28` and we try again.

I've modified the output procedure too. the `if defined` gate will only execute the `echo` if `line_%%C` is defined, so there'll be no empty lines. The downside is that the report will show the line number from the file.

The second procedure uses a fairly obvious method to serialise the output to produce the line numbers.

---

For example,

If the datafile contains

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3
>   Line 4
>   Line 5
>   Line 6
>   Line 7
>   Line 8

then if the parameters supplied are `3 5` meaning "lines 3 to 5 inclusive" then the output from

```
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do IF DEFINED line_%%C (echo %%C. !Line_%%C!)
```

will be

> 3. Line 3
> 4. Line 4
> 5. Line 5

(note each line has its *original* line number.

and the output from

```
SET /a count=0
For /L %%C in (1,1,%Counter%) Do IF DEFINED line_%%C (
 SET /a count +=1
 echo !count!. !Line_%%C!
)
```

will be

> 1. Line 3
> 2. Line 4
> 3. Line 5

(simply the same data but with the line numbers modified)

if you leave *both* of these output mechanisms in place, the output will be

> 3. Line 3
> 4. Line 4
> 5. Line 5
> 6. Line 3
> 7. Line 4
> 8. Line 5

that is, the first output concatenated with the second.

Comment: took me awhile to figure this blob out xD but alright so basically i would do something like:

    call text-read-lines-alt.bat 1 20

which would produce lines 1 to 20 in output.
i could easily add in a part that says if its at the end of the file stop outputting :D

one thing i dont get is the %%Z part. is that necessary? afaik thats a multiselect right? where i could use like this:

    call text-read-lines-alt.bat 1 20 23 25

which would produce 1-20 and 23-25

yes?

Comment: okay so that did not do what i thought it did:

http://prntscr.com/gybcbl

but... it works fine and i can just call the batch file twice if needed

thank you :D

would you like me to put you in as a credit?

Comment: also calling it once for 1-8 and again for 9-20 produces both successfully but also produces 1-12?
something is off and i cant tell what

Comment: Yes, executing using ....bat 1 20 23 25 will produce lines 1-20+23-25 inclusive. Your screenshot, if you examine it, is of two outputs, one from the first `for/L` after :echolines and then one for the second `for/L` Note that there is a small difference. The first shows the original line numbers from the file (21 & 22 missing) and the second shows the 23 lines produced with their new serial number in the output (1-23). Choose which you want and rem-out or delete the one you don't want. 9-20 produces 12 lines, shown with their original line numbers & then by the second `for/l` with new #s 1-12

Comment: how would i get around this if say i wanted to use this at any given time and have it run as if it was run for the first time? (resets on exit)

Comment: What is "this" that you want to "get around?"

Comment: i want to be able to run it many times in a row with different values without it doing that. basically, i want it to print say 1-8 9-20 without it also printing 1-12 (for whatever reason it does that [sorry i didnt get your explanation])

Comment: i seemed to have found the issue by moving the set counter outside the for loop. it executes twice: http://prntscr.com/gyoqp0

Comment: i fixed up the code so that it outputs correctly: http://prntscr.com/gyorxf & http://prntscr.com/gyos79 & http://prntscr.com/gyosk5
your code was fine you just added one to many echo for loops :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope [`msr.exe`](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/tree/master/tools) can help you for such file text processing.

`msr -p file-paths -L begin-line -N end-line` with `-PAC` to hide path/info/color.

But cannot read 2 ranges(`read lines 1 to 8 but also read lines 5 to 13`) at one time:

`msr -p test.txt -L 1 -N 8` + `msr -p text.txt -L 5 -N 13`

See following screenshot.

`msr.exe`/`msr.gcc*` is a single exe tool about 1.5MB no dependencies for file/pipe text processing on Windows and Linux in [my open project](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/README.md). See docs like [peformance comparision with grep and findstr](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/perf/summary-full-Windows-comparison.md) and [built-in usage doc by running exe](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-Windows.html) etc.
[image: file line range]

Comment: thank you the program works perfectly, but i would like to not use executables unless absolutely needed, this may prove useful for another project tho :D