# Print single lines, and a number of lines, with the contents i text file. Batch skript

Tags: batch-file

I would like to print single lines,or a number of lines, with the contents, between the desired line numbers (from the **n** to **m** lines numbers), in text file!
I have trouble printing lines, with the contents, **under number lines 10**, both single lines (eg, only 1, or 4, etc.), or several desired lines (eg from 1 to 9 or from 3 to 13 etc.) in the text file. To print liner, with contents, over number lines 10, both single lines (eg, only 11, or 16, etc.) and the desired number of lines (eg 10 to 19 or 14 to 16, etc.) works well. Where I'm wrong?

CODE:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "data.txt"') do (
if "%%a" EQU "%1" echo.%%b else (if "%%a" GTR "%1" if "%%a" LSS "%2"      echo.%%b))
::>>temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%%a" EQU "%1" echo.%%b else (if "%%a" GTR "%1" if "%%a" LSS "%2"      echo.%%b))
```

should be

```
if "%%a" EQU "%1" (echo.%%b) else (if "%%a" GTR "%1" if "%%a" LSS "%2"      echo.%%b))
```

as batch needs to differentiate between `echo %%b` and `echo %%b else ...` being alternative strings to `echo`.

Perhaps you should also see [This earlier example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761841/need-to-read-from-line-a-to-line-b-in-a-batch-file/46763519#46763519) which makes me feel that this is homework...